# I getting null wen return null access token

Tags: android

First, I have all configured (twitter keys, callback in the manifest, etc), then I do the call to twitter and get browser open, then I signIn in twitter and I accept the application, then the browser returns to application and try to get the response from twitter, but I get NULL as answer.

```
package com.example.fragmenttwitter;

import twitter4j.IDs;
import twitter4j.Twitter;
import twitter4j.TwitterException;
import twitter4j.TwitterFactory;
import twitter4j.auth.AccessToken;
import twitter4j.auth.RequestToken;
import twitter4j.conf.Configuration;
import twitter4j.conf.ConfigurationBuilder;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.SubMenu;


import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.PopupWindow;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {
    private final int LOGIN = 1;
    private final int TweetMenu = 2;
    private final int Retweet = 3;

    private final int FOWLOIING = 5;
    private final int SETTING = 6;
    private final int LOGOUT = 7;

    static String TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY = "xxx";
    static String TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET = "yyy";

    static String PREFERENCE_NAME = "twitter_oauth";
    static final String PREF_KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN = "oauth_token";
    static final String PREF_KEY_OAUTH_SECRET = "oauth_token_secret";
    static final String PREF_KEY_TWITTER_LOGIN = "isTwitterLogedIn";
    static final String TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL = "oauth://t4jsample";
    static final String URL_TWITTER_AUTH = "auth_url";
    static final String URL_TWITTER_OAUTH_VERIFIER = "oauth_verifier";
    static final String URL_TWITTER_OAUTH_TOKEN = "oauth_token";
    static boolean isLogin;

    private WebView wv;
    private String Url = null;
    Uri u;
    ImageButton close;
    Button cancel;
    Button btnUpdateStatus;
    EditText txtUpdate;
    TextView lblUpdate;
    TextView lblUserName;
    ProgressDialog pDialog;

    private PopupWindow Popup;

    private static Twitter twitter;
    private static RequestToken requestToken;
    private static SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences;
    private ConnectionDetector cd;

    AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();

    /// option menu

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu menu) {

        menu.add(Menu.NONE, LOGIN, Menu.NONE, "Login").setShowAsAction(
                MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);

        SubMenu submenu = menu.addSubMenu("Option");

        submenu.add(Menu.NONE, TweetMenu, Menu.NONE, "Tweet").setShowAsAction(
                MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS
                        | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);
        submenu.add(Menu.NONE, FOWLOIING, Menu.NONE, "Following")
                .setShowAsAction(
                        MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS
                                | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);
        submenu.add(Menu.NONE, SETTING, Menu.NONE, "Setting").setShowAsAction(
                MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS
                        | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);

        submenu.add(Menu.NONE, LOGOUT, Menu.NONE, "Logout").setShowAsAction(
                MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS
                        | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case LOGIN:

            if (item.getTitle().equals(("Login"))) {

                 loginToTwitter();
                //new Login().execute();
                item.setTitle("Logout");

            } else {
                logoutFromTwitter();
                item.setTitle("Login");
            }

            break;

        case TweetMenu:

            ImageButton bt1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
            bt1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main1);

            Button bt_status = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnUpdateStatus);
            bt_status.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {

                    final EditText etStaus = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtUpdateStatus);
                    String status = etStaus.getText().toString();

                    if (status.trim().length() > 0) {

                        new updateTwitterStatus().execute(status);
                    } else {

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Please enter status message",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });

            break;
        case Retweet:

            String retweet = txtUpdate.getText().toString();

            if (retweet.trim().length() > 0) {

                Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
                try {
                    twitter.retweetStatus(Long.parseLong(retweet));
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (TwitterException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Please enter Tweet message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }

            break;

        case FOWLOIING:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Fowllowing called",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 followingList();

            break;

        case SETTING:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "setting called",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case LOGOUT:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Logout called",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            logoutFromTwitter();
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY.trim().length() == 0
                || TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET.trim().length() == 0) {
            // Internet Connection is not present
            alert.showAlertDialog(MainActivity.this, "Twitter oAuth tokens",
                    "Please set your twitter oauth tokens first!", false);
            // stop executing code by return
            return;
        }

        cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());
        // Check if Internet present
        if (!cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {
            // Internet Connection is not present
            alert.showAlertDialog(this, "Internet Connection Error",
                    "Please connect to working Internet connection", false);
            // stop executing code by return
            return;
        }
        mSharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(
                "MyPref", 0);

        FragmentManager f = getSupportFragmentManager();
        TweetList tl = new TweetList();
        FragmentTransaction ft = f.beginTransaction().add(R.id.Lineary2, tl);
        ft.commit();

        btnUpdateStatus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnUpdateStatus);
        txtUpdate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtUpdateStatus);
        lblUpdate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblUpdate);
        lblUserName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblUserName); 

// check for already login in or not    

        if (!isTwitterLoggedInAlready()) {

             Uri uri=getIntent().getData();
            if (uri != null && uri.toString().startsWith(TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL)) {

                String verifier = uri
                        .getQueryParameter(URL_TWITTER_OAUTH_VERIFIER);

                try {

                     ///AccessToken accessToken = twitter.getOAuthAccessToken(requestToken, verifier);

                    AccessToken accessToken = twitter.getOAuthAccessToken(requestToken, verifier);

                    Editor e = mSharedPreferences.edit();
                    e.putString(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN, accessToken.getToken());
                    e.putString(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_SECRET,
                            accessToken.getTokenSecret());

                    e.putBoolean(PREF_KEY_TWITTER_LOGIN, true);
                    e.commit(); // save changes

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("Twitter Login Error", "> " + e.getMessage());

                }

            }
            else
              Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "not Login",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();   

        }

    }

    // code to login twitter
    private void loginToTwitter() {
        // Check if already logged in
        if (!isTwitterLoggedInAlready()) {
            ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
            builder.setOAuthConsumerKey(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY);
            builder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);
            Configuration configuration = builder.build();

            TwitterFactory factory = new TwitterFactory(configuration);
            twitter = factory.getInstance();


            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        //requestToken = twitter
                                //.getOAuthRequestToken(TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL);
                        // twitter.setOAuthConsumer(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY,TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);
                         requestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken(TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL);
                        MainActivity.this.startActivity(new Intent(
                                Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(requestToken
                                        .getAuthenticationURL())));
                    } catch (TwitterException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }).start();

        } 
    }

    //update the stastus from  twiiter app
    class updateTwitterStatus extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Updating to twitter...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            Log.d("Tweet Text", "> " + args[0]);
            String status = args[0];
            try {
                ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
                builder.setOAuthConsumerKey(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY);
                builder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);

                String access_token = mSharedPreferences.getString(
                        PREF_KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN, "");

                String access_token_secret = mSharedPreferences.getString(
                        PREF_KEY_OAUTH_SECRET, "");

                Log.i("Access Token", access_token);
                Log.i("Access Token secrate", access_token_secret);



                AccessToken accessToken = new AccessToken(access_token,
                        access_token_secret);

                Log.i("Access Token", accessToken.toString());

                Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory(builder.build())
                        .getInstance(accessToken);

                twitter4j.Status response = twitter.updateStatus(status);

                Log.d("Status", "> " + response.getText());
            } catch (TwitterException e) {
                Log.d("Twitter Update Error", e.getMessage());
            }
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {

            pDialog.dismiss();
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Status tweeted successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                    txtUpdate.setText("");
                }
            });
        }

    }
    //Logout from twitter app
    public void logoutFromTwitter() {
        // Clear the shared preferences
        Editor e = mSharedPreferences.edit();

        e.remove(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN);
        e.remove(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_SECRET);
        e.remove(PREF_KEY_TWITTER_LOGIN);
        e.commit();

    }

    private boolean isTwitterLoggedInAlready() {

        return mSharedPreferences.getBoolean(PREF_KEY_TWITTER_LOGIN, false);

    }

    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();


    }


}
```

Comment: Looks like you left your Twitter keys in there - might want to reset that.

Comment: @jayesh Did you solve your problem? I am getting NullPointerException, too. If you solved it then please tell me the solution in your case.

Comment: Any updates on what might have caused the issue and how to resolve it ?